# remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I currently have a django application, and have a PostgreSQL database. I have researched this error, and have found other answers on Stackoverflow, but none seem to answer my exact question. I am getting this error when a request is made to a server. Note that I am currently running my application locally. A lot of my views contain requests to the database:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Here are the configurations for the database that are in my settings.py file:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_postgrespool',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a connection leak somewhere.

Unless you changed the default settings, you get that message when you try to establish the 98th database connection.

You have to close the connections you don't need any more.

As with all resource leaks, increasing the limit won't hurt, it just buys you time until you hit the ceiling. Plug the hole!

Comment: How do I close the number of database connections with my configurations in my views.py file?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/55489/django.db.connection.close) can give you an idea.

Comment: Any fixes for this?

Comment: @SusajSN You yourself have to fix your code. You yourself have to make sure that connections are closed or reused.

Comment: what do you mean how own code? Django manages the connection to the dB, not his code. Are you saying there is nothing that can be done about this other than waiting for Django to to issue a fix for this?

Comment: @JasonGenX Yes, Django will create the connections, but it does not open connections just for fun. It will use a connection pool and open a connection if you request one and there is none available. The typical connection leak occurs if developers forget to close transactions or forget to return the connections to the pool.

Comment: how can I "forget to return the connection to the pool" if I'm simply using the django ORM for all read/write purposes?

Comment: @JasonGenX I have no idea, since I don't use ORMs. But people manage to do it, judging from the number of questions I see.